# Problemas con apache2 en Ubuntu 16

Tags: webservice, ubuntu, apache2, servidor

Configurando servidor web y hacer "service apache2 restart" en Ubuntu me devuelve estos errores: ¿Qué significa? ¿Qué solución tiene?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias! ; )

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo con _sudo_

Answer (score -1):

Intenta agregar `sudo` al comando.

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Horacio, agrega que realiza esto o en que ayuda?, revisar [answer] saludos!